# How is loading from a remote database typically managed? (conceptually)

Tags: ios, database

I'm making an app, and each view loads something differently from the remote database, so each view is going to have its own query. What would be the best way to manage database access in an app?

My possible solution:

- I'm wondering if it would be a good idea to create a separate NSObject file that functions as the data controller for everything that is stored to and loaded from the database. Theoretically, it would have a bunch of functions that take the data from the database and store it into the arrays. That way, all of the database access code is in one file, so I could just call these functions in the files as needed.

Is this the standard approach? Is there a better / more trivial / more robust approach? I'm just looking for the best way to keep my code clean, clear, and easy to update in the future.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something like this using a separate class to do the downloading, but not to store the data. This class defines a delegate protocol for sending data back to the caller. I create an instance of this class in any controller that needs to download something, and have it set itself as the delegate of that download class. I have one method in this class to which you pass in the URL, and in the call back methods (I used NSURLConnection), I call the delegate method which passes back the raw data (or error object) so each class can manipulate the data in its own way.